# Creating a Dictionary using list1 as keys and list2 as values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Complete the function to return a dictionary using `list1` as the keys and `list2` as the values

```
def createDict(list1, list2):
    my_dict = {'list1':'list1'}
    my_dict.update({'list1':list2})
    return my_dict 

createDict(['tomato', 'banana', 'lime'], ['red','yellow','green'])




# expected output: {'tomato': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow', 'lime': 'green'}

# getting {'list1': ['red', 'yellow', 'green']}
```

Comment: That output is exactly what you asked for, it's unclear why you thought it would be what you say you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "dict comprehension" special syntax:

```
my_dict = {key: value for key, value in zip(list1, list2)}
```

Or call the `dict` builtin with a packing of the keys and values:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

In both cases, the key is the `zip` built-in, which given two or more iterables will pick one item from each of them and pack them in a (usually temporary) tuple. The `dict` built-in consumes the iterable of 2-tuples and interpret then as key/value pairs. And in the dict-comprehension syntax, we explicitly use each component of the tuple generated by `zip` as key and value.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked! Is there a good reference that talks about this so I can learn about it?

Comment: I've written a little bit more about the solution now. My recomendation is to experiment with `zip` in the Python interactive console.

Comment: Thanks again appreciate the quick response and great information.

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip` and `dict`:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]

print(dict(zip(l1, l2)))
```

Output:

```
{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6}
```

This works because the `dict` constructor takes key-value tuples:

```
d = dict([(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
```

`zip` combines two lists into tuple pairs:

```
print(list(zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

The combination of these two functions builds your dictionary.